# Cannot extend express request

Tags: typescript, express

I'm trying to extend the `Request` interface of `Express` as:

```
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
interface IRequest extends Request {
  user: {
    id: string;
  }
}

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', auth, async (req: IRequest, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
    res.json(user);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error((e as Error).message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

but I got the following error:

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 3, '(path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>[]): Router', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(req: IRequest, res: Response) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
> Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
> Property 'user' is missing in type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>' but required in type 'IRequest'.
> Overload 2 of 3, '(path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>[]): Router', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(req: IRequest, res: Response) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
> Type '(req: IRequest, res: Response) => Promise' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.ts(2769)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typescript will not let you, because even if you typed it this way:

```
router.get('/', auth, async (req: IRequest, res: Response) => {
```

Typescript will still just assume that express will emit a `Request` and not an `IRequest`.

However, since you are probably monkey-patching the request object, you can use declaration merging to basically augment's Express' internal request object:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

If you don't want to globally make this change to `Request`, you could also use a assertion to make sure that it really was an `IRequest`:

```
router.get('/', auth, async (req: request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    assertIRequest(req);
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
    res.json(user);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error((e as Error).message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});

function assertIRequest(req: Request|IRequest): asserts req is IRequest {
  if (!req?.user?.id) throw new Error('Request was not an IRequest');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So there is no way to just specify the type as `IRequest`?

Comment: Yes, there is no way.

Comment: Before reading this answer, I had gone down a path of establishing a generic for `Request`, but that created other conflicts when trying to use other middleware. Can I assume from this answer it is typically best just to leave `Request` alone (with the exception of a module declaration to add objects onto `req`)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the interface `IRequest` is not being used for other purposes besides the above, one can follow the route in this [blog post](https://blog.logrocket.com/extend-express-request-object-typescript/#adding-custom-properties-to-the-request-type) by [Antonello Zanini](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html): just extend the interface defined by express, by adding a declaration file `src/types/express/index.d.ts` with the following content:

```
// src/types/express/index.d.ts

// to make the file a module and avoid the TypeScript error
export {}

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      user: {
        id: string;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As in the other answer, TypeScript's [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) mechanism will fuse the two declarations into one.

Hopefully, this late answer will be of use for some readers. I just had a similar [question](https://Import%20type%20%22Request%22%20from%20express-request-id).