# How to extend a request in express with typescript?

Tags: typescript, express

I am using typescript with express and merging the the request like that:

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      user: string;
    }
  }
}
```

the thing is that i want in some routes to create custom requests interfaces too, like that:

```
interface UserRequest extends Request {
  name: string
}
```

but when i use that in a route, typescript show an error in this part:

```
router.get(
  "/",
  getUserByPageAndAmount // Here
);
```

Here is the error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: UserRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
      Type '(req: UserRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
        Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
          Property 'name' is missing in type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' but required in type 'UserRequest'.ts(2769)
```

Comment: What's the version of express are you using?

Comment: The answer to a similar question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63603214/cannot-extend-express-request?rq=2